# Problems while trying to read a csv with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, io

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
Id, text, label
10101, string, label
```

Then I would like to put into a dataframe with pandas so I do this:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('/path/.csv')
 X, y = df['text'], df['label']
```

And I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    X, y, = df['text'], df['label']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1780, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1787, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1058, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2889, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1400, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 134, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3807)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3687)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 696, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12310)
  File "pandas/hashtable.pyx", line 704, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:12261)
KeyError: 'text'
```

Could anybody help me to understand what is happening and how to read correctly this file with pandas?, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: `X, y, = df['text'], df['label']` , shouldn't this be `X, y = df['text'], df['label']`

Comment: Sorry yes I edited thanks for the observation @Anmol_uppal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header in the CSV file is:

```
Id, text, label
```

Note that there are leading spaces in the column headers for columns 2 and 3. You can access the column by including the space:

```
x, y = df[' text'], df[' label']
```

Or specify the `skipinitialspace` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/path/x.csv', skipinitialspace=True)
x, y = df['text'], df['label']
```

The latter also removes the initial spaces from the column data too.